# Green's Theorem for 3 dimensions

Tags: greens-theorem

I'm reading *Introduction to Fourier Optics - J. Goodman* and got to this statements which is referred to as Green's Theorem:

> Let $U(P)$ and $G(P)$ be any two complex-valued functions of position, and let $S$ be a closed surface surrounding a volume $V$. If $U$, $G$, and their first and second partial derivatives are single-valued and continuous within and on $S$, then we have $$\iiint_V \Bigr(U \nabla^2 G - G \nabla^2 U\Bigr) dv = \iint_S \Bigr(U\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} -G\frac{\partial U}{\partial n}\Bigr)ds$$ where $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ signifies a partial derivative in the outward normal direction at each point on $S$.

I remembered to have learned about Green's Theorem in the mathematics courses but did not recall this form. I looked it up and got to what I remembered, that is a 2-dimensional case given by $$\iint_S \Bigr(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\Bigr)dxdy=\int_C Qdx+ Pdy$$ which could be considered a particular case of Stokes' Theorem.

Are the two formulas related (which means I missed the link, in which case, can someone suggest some directions), or are they different formulas and the author in the book misfortunately used "Green's Theorem"?

Answer (score 3):

I searched further and after some luck with the terms used in the search engine I got to what are called [Green's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities). The formula I had trouble with is the second identity.

Now that I found the "correct" name of it, I could look for links to the Stokes theorem and got to [this material](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/5233-S96/5233-l21.pdf), so if someone has a similar problem, you can start from these.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is related to the Gauss theorem. Note that
$$ U\nabla^2 G - G\nabla^2 U = \nabla \cdot (U\nabla G - G\nabla U)$$
So from the Gauss theorem
$$ \iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot X dV = \iint_{\partial \Omega} X \cdot dS$$
you get he cited statement. Gauss theorem is sometimes grouped with Green's theorem and Stokes' theorem, as they are all special cases of a general theorem for k-forms:
$$ \int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega $$