# Is there a relationship between the curved surface area of an extruded region and its volume?

Tags: integration, volume, surface-integrals, line-integrals

If I have a closed, simply connected region in the $z$-plane, and I 'extrude' this region vertically by a height $h$, what is the relationship between the curved surface area and the volume of the extrusion?

Answer (score 0):

Green's theorem is something like this for 2 dimensions. I don't know if it has a 3D version. But I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539368/greens-theorem-for-3-dimensions)